# C# Setting a Form like always TopMost, but interaction is always possible with other windows

Tags: c#, window, overlay

[image]

This is a screenshot of a `Form`. It's basically just those two lines at the top of a screen, when you hover them this little window pops up. I just wonder what these two lines might be.

I did not find any information on the internet on how to achieve something familiar. I just want to know what idea is behind that, maybe some sample code would be nice to illustrate this idea.

Is this just some sort of *custom window*? Is `WPF` probably the way to go then? If so, how is it possible to set a `Form` always visible and usable (it is not required to click on the `Form` to get the focus to be able to interact with it) even though it can't be set as `TopMost` `Form`?

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

Because I can still interact with other windows, while the *two lines custom form* is still visible and overlaying all other windows. But under no circumstance this *two lines custom form* gets overlayed. What idea is behind this *custom Form*?

---

**Update:**

After some additional research on the internet, it seems like the `TopMost` property doens't behave as you expect sometimes. I just tested it a few more times and now it is behaving exactly the way I described I want it to be.

---

**Update on how this *two lines Form* work:**

Imagine you have any window open in FullScreen. But the *two lines Form* is at the top of your screen. It hovers all other windows, but doesn't declare it's own space like an `AppBar`. The *two lines Form* gets never hidden, so there is no `AutoHide` involved. It's just the window with "*Screenshot region*", ...that pops up once the *two lines Form* get's hovered. Furthermore the *two lines Form* is bound to the top of the screen.

Comment: So why again you cannot use TopMost to achieve that?

Comment: @Evk I think you don't understand what I mean exactly. Imagine you start any program, so a new window popped up. You can use this window as usual, but the *two lines custom window* is always visible. When you hover this window you can instantly interact with it, once you don't hover it anymore the window before got the focus back (this is easy to do), but how can the *two lines custom window* overlay *all* windows even though I can interact with *all windows*. By default when I interact with a window it gets set as *TopMost* and overlays all other windows, execept this one. But how?

Comment: Topmost true does just what you describe - it overlays all windows, including that one which is now active (focused), and always stays on top of all windows. So that two line custom window is, I guess, just very small window with Topmost true, which on hover shows another window (or expands itself) and when you move mouse out - shrinks back.

Comment: Hmm I feel quite confused/dumb right now... . I just tested it and it didn't work out that way you described it. I did set the small window as `TopMost` but once I focused another window, it hovered the small one. Do I need to subscribe to some `TopMost` `Form` `Changed` event, so once it changes to set the small window to `TopMost = true` again?

Comment: Well I missed that you are talking about WinForms. I was talking about WPF, though I would be quite surprised if there is big difference for how Topmost works. Can you test with WPF and see if you observe the same?

Comment: @Evk I just tested it at first with `WPF`, the result is it worked out fine. Now I went to `WinForms`. Surprisingly it does work now the way I always wanted it to be. I am confused what is different now than a few minutes ago, because I didn't change anything. At least it works now. I just feel so silly right now, I could have not asked a more easy/obvious/dumb question.

Comment: @Evk Hmm, however what you post just a short answer what you pointed out to me? So I can award to you the bounty and the rep is at least not gone. Or do you think deleting is a better way, since this questions seems now more than just obvious... ?

Comment: Well there are a lot of questions if you google "winforms topmost doesn't work", so it seems for one reason or another this property might not behave as you expect sometimes, so it's not dumb question. Also I'm not sure it's even possible to delete question with a bounty.

Comment: @Evk Ok, you are the expert. :-) So as you speak you would rather leave the question here due to the *buggy* behaviour of the *TopMost* property. Would you like a small *50 rep award* then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just fine with `TopMost` = `true` (in WinForms and in WPF too). TopMost means window will be always displayed over any other windows without this flag set (so another topmost window *might* overlay your topmost window), including currently active window. So most likely what is on your screenshot is just topmost window with very small size aligned to the top of screen, which shows another window (or expands itself) on mouse over and hides that window (or shrinks itself) when mouse is out. I'm not an expert on WinForms, so if that doesn't work in some cases for you - you might find some information in google about why and when it doesn't work (for example some people claim it doesn't work when you run application from Visual Studio, so ensure you run it standalone while testing). But in general TopMost property should do just what you describe.